# Override multiple classes

Tags: css

If I am trying to override a specific tag inside multiple classes, do I have to explicitly write that out for each class or is there a way to combine them. For example I have:

```
.class1 { }
.class2 { }
.class1 h2 {
    <!-- some code -->
}
```

And I want to apply the code for h2 tags in class1 also to h2 tags in class2, is there a way to define it for both class1 and class2 without writing the code twice?

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/ http://compass-style.org/ http://lesscss.org/ etc

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435116/can-i-specify-multiple-css-classes-with-one-class-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [Selector Grouping](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping):

```
.class1 h2,
.class2 h2 { ... }
```

Quoting the spec:

> *In this example, we condense three rules with identical declarations into one. Thus,*
>
> ```css
> h1 { font-family: sans-serif }
> h2 { font-family: sans-serif }
> h3 { font-family: sans-serif }
> ```
>
> *is equivalent to:*
>
> ```css
> h1, h2, h3 { font-family: sans-serif }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. Don't know why other people said it couldn't be done or gave links to language extensions

Answer (score 0):

if you want css to applied for all h2 in page, you can define it page level. But if you want to apply for only class1 & class2 , you will have to write it twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have same css style in more than one class, then you should combine those class, in order to optimize the code.

You can group the css class.

```
.class1 h1{ ........}
.class2 h2{ ........ }
```

It means, that h2 element will have class1 css style.

```
.class1,.class2{..........}
```

It means, that class1, class2 both have same css style

Answer (score 0):

```
 <h2 class="class1 class2">This is my taunt</h2>
```

This is the standard way to implement multiple classes.  As a general rule, you should define classes that you know in advance will overlap to exclude declarations you know will be in the other class.  Make a third class for common property/value pairs.